# Python - Align Tkinter Label Text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm trying to get the text inside the `l_Title` label (in the class `StartPage`) to right align however neither `anchor` nor `justify` appear to work.

I get no error message and one thing which may be effecting it is that I'm using ttk labels rather than tk ones, however there's no change when I change back to tk labels.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

def To_Print(self):
    xf = Enter_Inputs(self,'xf')
    print('xf = ', xf)

def Enter_Inputs(self,x): # Enter inputs from values typed in

      xf_In = int(self.e_xf.get())

      if x == 'xf':
          x = float(xf_In)/100 

      return x


class TestApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


        self.l_Title = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT, 
                              justify="right", anchor="e")
        self.l_Title.grid(row=0, columnspan = 2)


        self.l_xf = tk.Label(self, text="% xA of Feed")
        self.l_xf.grid(row=1)

        self.e_xf = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e_xf.grid(row=1, column=1)


        self.b_Run = tk.Button(self, text="Click to Run", command=lambda: To_Print(self))
        self.b_Run.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan = 2)  


app = TestApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Label adjusts it's size to be a perfect fit for the text.  `justify` only works if the Label is bigger than the text.

In your case it's much easier to define the position of the Label, not the text within the Label:

```
self.l_Title.grid(row=0, columnspan = 2, sticky='e')
```